# No Internet access from pod in Oracle Kubernetes Engine (OKE)

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Using Oracle Kubernetes Engine, I created a managed basic Kubernetes cluster using the "quick create" flow with the following spécifications:

- 4 worker nodes
- public subnet
- Oracle linux boot image
- Ampere A1 Flex VM shape

Here is a link to the documentation on the [oracle quick create flow](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengcreatingclusterusingoke_topic-Using_the_Console_to_create_a_Quick_Cluster_with_Default_Settings.htm)

As per documentation and configuration of the Route table linked to the internet gateway i should be able to access internet from within a pods but this is not the case.

To debug internet access issues i have done the following steps :

Egress traffic to internet seems blocked after a few hops.

```bash
# run an alpine pod in the default namespace and get shell using a custom alpine image instrumented with curl and traceroute 
kubectl run -it alpine --image antoineleguillou/alpine-curl:latest
```

```bash
# dns check
nslookup google.com
```

```bash
# dns check output
Server:     10.96.5.5
Address:    10.96.5.5:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4007:80e::200e

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.214.174
```

```bash
# traceroute check 
traceroute google.com
```

```bash
# traceroute check output
traceroute to google.com (142.250.179.78), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  oke-csd46tj66qq-nfqvrwtdpqq-s5khezb2fnq-0.sub9da357a0c.andrew.oraclevcn.com (10.0.10.106)  0.007 ms  0.006 ms  0.005 ms
 2  140.204.198.4 (140.204.198.4)  0.006 ms  140.204.198.7 (140.204.198.7)  0.092 ms  140.204.198.12 (140.204.198.12)  0.068 ms
 3  *  *  *
```

I really don't know how to debug this issue further, thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution @antoine?